Error thrown when trying to open file for Chrome Extension - User gesture required
I'm developing a Chrome extension using manifest V3. The extension allows the user to download a file onto their default directory. The user is then presented with a button to click on to open the downloaded file. However, when the button is clicked I get the following error Uncaught (in promise) Error: User gesture required. I have an event listener bound to the button click within content_script.js and I send a chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "open-clicked" }); to the service_worker.js which has the logic for opening the file: chrome.downloads.open(result.lastDownloadId);.
Why is the user gesture error being thrown when the user has indeed clicked the button to open it?
content_script.js
let actionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-myapp-chrome]');

actionButtons.forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let action = this.getAttribute('data-myapp-chrome');
        if(action === 'download-button') {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                action: "download-clicked"
            });
        } else if(action === 'open-button') {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                action: "open-clicked"
            });
        }
    });
});

service_worker.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.action === "download-clicked") {
        downloadClickedAction();
    } else if(request.action === "open-clicked") {
        openClickedAction();
    }
});

function openClickedAction() {
    // open the downloaded file
    try {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(["lastDownloadId"], function (result) {
            chrome.downloads.search({id: result.lastDownloadId}, function(searchResult) {
                // discontinue if file does not exist
                if (!searchResult || searchResult.length < 1 || !searchResult[0].exists) {
                    throw EXTENSION_STATUS_OPEN_FAILED;
                }
                chrome.downloads.open(result.lastDownloadId);
                catchApiError(EXTENSION_STATUS_OPEN_FAILED);
            });
        });
    } catch(e) {
        sendMessage({status: EXTENSION_STATUS_OPEN_FAILED});
    }
}

manifest.json
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "description": "My App description",
  "permissions": [
    "downloads",
    "downloads.open",
    "notifications",
    "storage"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "file://*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service_worker.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost/*",
                  "https://localhost/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "48": "images/icon-48.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3
}


This could use a line number to help define where the error occurs. IDK extensions well, but from what I've read the function being used to handle the event has to be synchronous. Since the event handler here is firing off another event, that's asynchronous (not async/await, but event-based async).
